# how to stream live webcam in unity 3d?

Tags: webcam, unity-game-engine

At the moment i am being able to see my own webcam in unity3d as a texture using this simple tutorial
http://www.ikriz.nl/2011/12/23/unity-video-remake
Now i want to know that how can i see someone's else webcam in unity 3d?
can any body give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help any one who would find this helpful in future, i have done this by using a flash client that takes the live stream and send it to a local server which was written in .Net.
and that .net server then sends the stream to our script which was running in unity3D. and that script was placed on any plane in your model , so showing you the received stream.
It was a bit laggy but it was working :)

Comment: i am trying to achieve this at the moment. Can you provide anymore details please?

Comment: me 2. Can you provide more detail plz?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean under 'someone's else webcam'? Actually you can open socket connection between two computers, stream 'someone's else' webcam via socket and show a picture in your application. 
An application for 'someone's else' can be written in any language/framework.

Comment: it wasn't so simple in unity so i was just looking for some pointers , but i have figured it out :)
thanks anyway

Comment: @chossen-addict I am wondering, how did you accomplish this? I am trying to figure out this same thing. Any tips would be appreciated!